# "instructed not to" vs "instructed to not"

Tags: grammar

As per above title.

The complete sentence would be:
You are hereby instructed not to proceed with any construction works for the units shown on the plan attached.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For almost all verbs, *to not V* and *not to V* are identical in effect and meaning. There's a fine-grained technical distinction that most English speakers (including native speakers) won't capture; I've previously addressed this [elsewhere on english.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198341/in-the-imperative-what-is-right-to-say-remember-to-not-do-or-remember-not-to/204593#204593).

A difference exists, however, for a small subset of verbs where it is possible to relate to the object in two ways. For instance:

> I do not like *to eat eggs.*

versus

> I like *not to eat eggs.*

In the former, I am saying that *I do not enjoy eating eggs*. In the latter, I am saying that *I enjoy the fact that I am not eating eggs*. (The italicized portions of the sentences in the blockquotes represent the objects of the verb in each case.)

---

For almost all uses of *to instruct* that I can think of, the meaning will be identical. But in the case of your full sentence, I think they would have identical meanings:

> You are hereby instructed *not to proceed* with any construction works for the units shown on the plan attached.

vs.

> You are hereby instructed *to not proceed* with any construction works for the units shown on the plan attached.

I personally would prefer the latter construction (since you are in fact being instructed to do something, and it is merely the content of the instruction that is negated), but I think I'm probably in the minority on that.

Comment: But how about _I like to not eat eggs_? The construction you're talking about is just [Neg-Raising](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/117681/15299) with _like_, a completely different kettle of fish.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's a "just". Maybe we use English differently, but it's an important stylistic concern for me as a philosopher, which, rather than linguistics, is the context where I'm familiar with it. Also, the link inside the answer you link to is dead.

Answer (score 0):

*Instructed not to* would be the better choice.

Though there is nothing completely ungrammatical about the other option, you wouldn't find it being used as much, roughly 1 in 10 cases. Take a look at this [nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=instructed+not+to%2C+instructed+to+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinstructed%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinstructed%20to%20not%3B%2Cc0) for the picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Would have upvoted, but I seem to need 15 reputation =)